Localization of the category of modules where weak equivalences are maps inducing isomorphisms on all fibers
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let's say that a map of $R$-modules $f: M \to N$ is a weak equivalence if for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$, the induced map  of $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \left( \quotient{R}{\mathfrak{p}} \right)_\mathfrak{p}$-modules $\tilde{f}: \left( \quotient{M}{\mathfrak{p}} \right)_\mathfrak{p} \to \left( \quotient{N}{\mathfrak{p}} \right)_\mathfrak{p}$ is an isomorphism. Consider the localization $\mathcal{C}$ of $R\mathsf{-Mod}$ at the class of weak equivalences. Geometrically, viewing a module as a vector bundle over the spectrum, this means that we want to do everything fiberwise. Does the resulting category have a common name? It seems like a natural construction. What properties does it have? In particular, is it an abelian category?
For example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}$, the map $\mathbb{Z}_{\langle 2 \rangle} \to \mathbb{Q} \oplus \quotient{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle 2 \rangle}$ is a weak equivalence which was not an isomorphism.

Not a complete answer, but if $R$ has a unique minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, this category is equivalent to $R/\mathfrak{p}-\mathbf{Mod}$ via $M\mapsto M/\mathfrak{p}M$.

I don't agree with the interpretation. The fiber at $p$ is $M_p / p M_p = M \otimes_R Q(R/p)$, not $M/pM$.

@MartinBrandenburg I think this is the question I ment to ask. I'll edit it.

In your example, presumably you mean the product, and not the direct sum?

@ManuelAraujo I realized that my example doesn't work. But I think I have found a new example.

If there are only finitely many prime ideals, then the localization is the product over $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$-Mod for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$, which is an abelian category (even semisimple!). I have no idea if that description also holds in general.

It seems a good first step is passing to the reduced ring by quotienting by the nilradical. This shouldn’t change the localized category.

@LukasHeger I deleted the answer because it doesn’t work. The functor doesn’t have a left adjoint; it has a right adjoint which takes $M$ to $\prod M_\mathfrak{p}$. Unfortunately, the counit of this adjunction is only an isomorphism when there are finitely many prime ideals.
